# Is there a solution to fixed cos math function in golang

Tags: function, go, trigonometry

I am trying to use cos function from math API in golang, but for some reason the function is returning an incorrect value. Is there a known solution for this problem?

**Code:**

```
    fmt.Println("cos(pi/2):", math.Cos(math.Pi / 2))
    fmt.Println("sen(pi/2):", math.Sin(math.Pi / 2))
```

**Output:**

cos(pi/2): 6.123233995736757e-17

sen(pi/2): 1

Comment: As far as I can tell its just a rounding error in the library.  The source code is here: https://golang.org/src/math/sin.go?h=math

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3004

Answer (score 7):

The [cosine of pi / 2 is *zero*](https://www.google.com/search?q=cos(pi+%2F+2)).

What you're seeing is just a slight floating point inaccuracy. It's correctly returning "almost zero".

See: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).